# Qt: How to properlly use setUpdatesEnabled to help GUI performance?

Tags: c++, qt

How to properlly use setUpdatesEnabled to help GUI performance?
 Here is my code:

```
void uavTabGroup::updateMgr()
{

    setUpdatesEnabled(false);
    for (updateCtr = 0; updateCtr < max_num; updateCtr++)
    {
        if (infoView[updateCtr] != NULL)// its a child widget to the current widget
        {
            infoView[updateCtr]->updateDisplay();
        }
    }
    setUpdatesEnabled(true);
}
```

However, there is no improvement compared to don't use `setUpdatesEnalbed()` function, am I doing this wrong. BTW, all the `infoView[i]` are in a girdlayout of the current widget.

Now I am doing the updating in this way:

void uavTabGroup::updateMgr()
{

```
if (updateCtr >= max_num)
    updateCtr = 0;

if (infoView[updateCtr] != NULL)
{
    infoView[updateCtr]->updateDisplay();
}

updateCtr++;
```

}

And trigger the updateMgr at a higher frequency, and the child widgets are getting updated one by one sequentially.
But someone told me this is wrong... So which is the correct solution?

Comment: What is `updateDisplay()` supposed to do? I can't find any documentation about it in Qt Assistant. Btw `setUpdatesEnabled(bool)` enables `update()` and `repaint()`, which are used to call a paint event on a widget.

Comment: @Michael, it is a function of my own. It simply updates some text in a QLabel and the background color of the QLabel.